# Spring JPA Criteria Builder specific columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using JPA criteria builder to query Database for the records. However, I want to return specific columns from a table using JPA criteria API.

Currently, my implementation returns full object. But, I want to return only specific columns and those columns could be dynamic. **Below code will query on Person table and returns Full-Object of Person.**

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> root = query.from(Person.class);
    query.select(cb.equal(root.get("id"), 1));

    TypedQuery<Person> result = em.createQuery(query);
    List<Person> personList = result.getResultList();
```

I know we can create a minified class like PersonMini which will include only a specific field like below but, In my case, the columns could be dynamic and based on the user's preference.

```
class PersonMini {
     private long id;
     private String name;
     // .. constructor and getter/setter
}
```

It's not feasible to create a separate mini-classes of Person. Has anyone solved such issue before or could you please suggest another approach if that would solve my problem.

**EDIT**:

As mentioned in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect-java.util.List-).

> If the type of the criteria query is CriteriaQuery for some user-defined class X (i.e., a criteria query object created by passing a X class argument to the createQuery method), the elements of the list passed to the multiselect method will be passed to the **X constructor and an instance of type X will be returned for each row**.

If I use **multiselect** method and use **PersonMini** Class then I will need a constructor for each and every combination of the fields. Because the selection of the fields is done by Users. selection of fields is not static.

Suppose, in PersonMini class I have 3 fields. *Id, Name, and City* then User could choose *Id and Name*, *Name and City*, *City(alone)*, *Id(alone)*, *Id and City*. For each combination I need constructor otherwise it will throw error runtime.

For two-three field, it is feasible to have a different combination of constructor but for 15-20 field it is not.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't see any solution in your referred link. currently, I'm using the same Class CrittriaBuilder.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect-java.util.List-

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the comment.you are right I could use multiselect(List<Selection<?>> selectionList)
but the issue is "selection of columns is done by Users" and could be any columns of that Class.

Comment: So what? It means that you'll have to create your list of selections to pass to multiselect() based on what the user chose. If you're looking for a magic method named "guessWhatTheUserWantsToSelectAndDoItForMe()", I'm sorry, but it doesn't exist. You'll have to write some code by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet No. You didn't understand my problem clearly. I know how to pass users' selected columns in the method.

Comment: @JBNizet suppose in PersonMini class I have 3 fields. **Id, Name, and City** then User could choose **Id and Name, Name and City, City(alone), Id(alone), Id and City**. For each combination I need constructor otherwise it will throw error runtime.

Comment: why can't you use HQL query to filter the selected columns..?
But the return type will be list<map> so you need to convert it into list<person> using model mapper.

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 that's the problem. I could use Tuple as well for return type with criteria api but then I need to convert to Person class.